# Why 'null' is passed as argument in functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was going through some code and couldn't understand why null is being passed as a program argument. Can someone please explain this?

```
callback(null, data);
```

The handler code:

```
function callbackHandler(error, ...rest) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else {
        console.log("No error"+rest);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please share the code of `callback()` so, we can explain.

Comment: Sure I'll add the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a pattern - the first argument if not null indicates some error occurred in the operation.

```
err = { "message": "Oops!"};
callback(err, null);
```

If it is `null`, the operation in question has completed successfully and is giving back the `data` via the `callback`.

Comment: Can you also explain why the rest parameters are enclosed in ' [ ] ' or should I ask the question in a new thread?

Comment: Can you also share how it is handled for both the cases? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So in the function definition I'll be checking if the first parameter is 'null' so handle it as 'Not error' and when second parameter is 'null' handle it as 'error' condition. Right?

Comment: Yes we first check if an error has happened and then proceed.